# How to remove zeros from zero-left numbers (leading zeros) in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, leading-zero

I have this dataframe

```
df = data.frame(x = c('01','02','03','04','05'))
df
```

And the objective is to have the output as follows :

```
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

Comment: If you wanted to keep it a character, you could also do `sub("0", "", df$x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
df$x <- as.integer(df$x)
```